# Eclipse Console not showing Exceptions

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc, logging, console, tomcat7

I´m running a Spring-mvc Webapplication on a Tomcat 7 all operated in Eclipse. The Problem i got is, that while running, the Eclipse Console is showing everything but Exceptions. The Application runs smooth, also STOUTS are shown in the Console. NPE´s are beeing ignored, even though they are forced by me.

Is there any chance someone knows, how they could have been disabled?
Best Regards

the logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true">
    <!-- http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#LevelChangePropagator -->
    <contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator" />

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE_ALL"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">

        <file>${catalina.base}/logs/XXX.log</file>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${catalina.base}/logs/XXX.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 100MB -->
                <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <!-- keep 30 days worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{ISO8601} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE_AUDIT"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">

        <file>${catalina.base}/logs/XXX-Protokoll.log</file>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${catalina.base}/logs/XXX-Protokoll.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 100MB -->
                <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <!-- keep 30 days worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>90</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{ISO8601} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <logger name="jdbc.sqlonly" level="INFO" />

    <logger name="AUDIT" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_AUDIT" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="WARN" />


    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_ALL" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

the web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    metadata-complete="true" version="2.5">
    <description>EEM</description>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:application-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- OpenSessionInView -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>entityManagerFactoryBeanName</param-name>
            <param-value>entityManagerFactory</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.orchestra.conversation.servlet.ConversationManagerSessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Production</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <description>Enables the ui:debug facelets tag.</description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.EXPRESSION_FACTORY</param-name>
        <param-value>de.odysseus.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.COMPRESS_STATE_IN_SESSION</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.LOG_WEB_CONTEXT_PARAMS</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/springsecurity.taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>smoothness</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/face1.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Are you logging any logging framework like Log4j ? If so please paste the configuration here ( web.xml and log4j config file)

Comment: i have a logback.xml
I´ll add both files to the description

Answer (score 0):

Have you set a `NullPointerException` breakpoint to figure out where it's happening? please give a try. Hope it will work.

Comment: Guess his problem is to display exceptions on Log.

Comment: i added a button method that throws a NPE. While debugging i get redirected to a FastclassByCGLIB.invoke method. But I cant really get any usefull informations out of that